# Passing a specific function to a template

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm trying to pass a function to a template, and so far I obtained this:

```
template <typename T, typename U> void special_sort(std::vector<T>& container, std::vector<U>& ordering_container,
    std::function<std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>>(std::vector<U>&)>& sort_function) {

    sort_function(ordering_container);
}
```

In the main, I declared this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>> sort_function(std::vector<int>&) {
    std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>> a;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> test_container = {"a", "b", "c"};
    std::vector<int> test_ordering_container = {4,7,2};

    auto a = sort_function(test_ordering_container);
    special_sort<std::string, int>(test_container, test_ordering_container, sort_function(test_ordering_container));
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error (active)    E0304   no instance of function template "special_sort" matches the argument list   Objective_challenge C:\Users\mdp11\source\repos\Objective_challenge\Objective_challenge\main.cpp    21                  argument types are: (`std::vector<std::string`, `std::allocator<std::string>>`, `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>`, `std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>`, `std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>>>`)

What is that I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? btw `sort_function(test_ordering_container)` this is not  a function, but you call the function and it returns a vector and a vector is not a function ;)

Comment: I'm trying to get that template function to receive 3 parameters, a vector of T, a vector of U, and a function that can sort the second vector, but I want to call that function inside the template "special_sort"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes. First, use this:

```
special_sort<std::string, int>(test_container, test_ordering_container, sort_function);
```

instead of

```
special_sort<std::string, int>(test_container, test_ordering_container, sort_function(test_ordering_container));
```

You were passing the result of the function instead of the function itself.

You also need to declare the argument of `special_sort` as

```
const std::function<std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>>(std::vector<U>&)>& sort_function
```

instead of

```
std::function<std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>>(std::vector<U>&)>& sort_function
```

Because `sort_function` refers to a standard function call, it needs to be converted to a `std::function` to be able to call `special_sort`. However, this implicit conversion will create a temporary object which cannot be passed as reference. But a const reference is accepted for temporary objects.

Answer (score 2):

So you got two mistakes here.

The first is this:

```
special_sort<std::string, int>(
    test_container, test_ordering_container, 
    sort_function(test_ordering_container)
);//     --------^-----------------------^
```

Instead of sending the function, you call it and send the result.

The compiler complains about a vector not convertible to a `std::function`.

```
special_sort<std::string, int>(
    test_container, test_ordering_container, 
    sort_function
);//        ^------ the function itself
```

---

The second error is taking the function by mutable reference.

The type of a function is **not** `std::function`. The type of `sort_function` is a function pointer type.

The class `std::function` is a polymorphic wrapper around any callable. So a lambda type, a function object type, a function pointer and such can all be contained in a `std::function` in a type erased way.

When sending a function pointer as parameter to your function, it has to create a temporary `std::function`. But the problem here is that temporary cannot be bound to mutable reference, only constant ones:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void special_sort(
    std::vector<T>& container,
    std::vector<U>& ordering_container,
    std::function<std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>>(std::vector<U>&)> const& sort_function
) { //                            -----------------------------------------------------^

}
```

Or you can also use a template parameter. You don't need runtime polymorphism and type erasure in that particular case. Do what the STL does and simply take the callable by value:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename F>
void special_sort(
    std::vector<T>& container,
    std::vector<U>& ordering_container,
    F sort_function
) {
    // much simpler
    // you can still do:
    // sort_function(ordering_container)
}
```